# Update field in db in django from views with existing form, won't update because of "Integrity Error"

Tags: python, django

My first post, really newbie at programming. I am having issues to update a field in a form. I'll try to explain my best.
I have a Catalog class (products or services) with a couple fields, 2 of them must be unique.

**models.py**

```
class Catalogo(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, help_text="Product or service name", unique=True
    )
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Part Number", unique=True)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=15, choices=categoria, verbose_name="Category"
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        help_text="Item description",
        verbose_name="Descripción",
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text="Updated")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "product and service"
        verbose_name_plural = "products and services"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Then i have a form to gather the information

**forms.py**

```
categories = [("Product", "Product"), ("Service", "Service")]

class NewProductForm(forms.Form):

    item = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Item",
        max_length=100,
    )
    sku = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Part number",
        max_length=50,
    )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=categories,
        label="Category",
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Item description",
    )
```

Now for the views...i created 2 functions, one for adding new product/service and one for updating

**views.py**

```
def new_prod_serv(request):
    new_form = NewProductForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_form = NewProductForm(request.POST)

        if new_form.is_valid():
            new_product = Catalogo(
                item=new_form["item"].value(),
                sku=new_form["sku"].value(),
                category=new_form["category"].value(),
                description=new_form["description"].value(),
            )
            new_product.save()
            return redirect("products-services")

        else:
            print(new_form.errors)

    context = {"formulario": new_form}

    return render(request, "SkytechnosaApp/comercial/nuevoproducto.html", context)



def update_prod_serv(request, primarykey):
    product_service = Catalogo.objects.get(id=primarykey)
    item = product_service.item
    sku = product_service.sku
    category = product_service.category
    description = product_service.description
    form_data = {
        "item": item,
        "sku": sku,
        "category": category,
        "description": description,
    }
    form = NewProductForm(initial=form_data)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewProductForm(request.POST, initial=form_data)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("products-services")

        else:
            print(form.errors)

    context = {"form": form}

    return render(request, "SkytechnosaApp/comercial/nuevoproducto.html", context)
```

The html works okay, the problem i'm facing is when i click on edit...it will populate the form with the information of the product or service i want to edit (that's fine), but then i make the changes on the comment field for example (just want to update comment) and then I get the error IntegrityError at /comercial/productos/nuevo
UNIQUE constraint failed: Comercial_catalogo.sku

It's like it's trying to create another product, because when i go back and i edit all the fields, and click on save, i see another product created, but I just wanted to update, rather than create a new product....what i am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form code you pasted in your question is not complete (it's just a `form.Form` not a `form.ModelForm`, and yet you called `form.save()`)

**forms.py**

```
class NewProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    item = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Item",
        max_length=100,
    )
    sku = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Part number",
        max_length=50,
    )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=categories,
        label="Category",
    )
    description = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        label="Item description",
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = Catalogo
```

After that, if you want to update an instance (instead of creating one), you have to tell the ModelForm which instance it has to update:

**view.py**

```
def update_prod_serv(request, primarykey):
    ...
    instance = Catalogo.objects.get(id=primarykey)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewProductForm(request.POST, instance=instance) # you don't need to use `initial` since 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    ...
```

That said, it's generally best to have just ONE view for creating and updating. If you want to see how that works let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Grand Phuba, so better to use ModelForm rather than form to pass the instance...i'll try and let you know

Comment: It worked like charme wifn modelform...thanks a lot Grand Phuba